# Visual Studio project is loaded information

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution, visual-studio-project

So I am working on a solution with a lot of projects with multiple developers using SVN. There are some projects that are specific for me that I want loaded but for others they might not be relevant.

So my question is, where does Visual Studio store information about a project begin loaded and what is the proper way to commit project/solution settings with out ruining it for others?

An example could be that I just added a new project to the solution and I want to commit these changes, but I don't want to commit whether or not a project is loaded/reloaded (Since other developers have to reload them again).

EDIT: I found the answer here [When I unload projects in visual studio, where does VS save this setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275753/when-i-unload-projects-in-visual-studio-where-does-vs-save-this-setting?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When i unload projects in visual studio, where does VS save this setting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275753/when-i-unload-projects-in-visual-studio-where-does-vs-save-this-setting)

Answer (score 1):

When you add projects to a solution, they will get loaded when the solution opens.

If using source control, if such a solution is updated and contains new projects, they will get loaded.

One way of dealing with this is to create multiple solutions - solutions that only have relevant projects. These solutions *can* be part of source control, but don't have to, though if you don't add them to source control you risk having projects in source control that only you have a solution reference to.