# Project remains unloaded in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

When I start VS2010, one of my projects is unloaded. I reload the project and restart Visual Studio and the project is again unloaded.

Where is the setting that determines which projects are unloaded? I have looked in the solution and project, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Provide more info. What is the GUID of the project type causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is stored in the .suo file.

You could try deleting that file (maybe it is corrupt).  Then when you reopen the solution all the projects witll be loaded, but hopefully you will be able to unload the ones you want and get back into a happy state.

This was also discussed here: [When I unload projects in visual studio, where does VS save this setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275753/when-i-unload-projects-in-visual-studio-where-does-vs-save-this-setting)